# Silently fails to write build output

Tags: angular, typescript1.8

I have a setup with `angular2`, rc5, where the folder structure is as follows:

```
.
| - wwwroot
|   - app
|   - lib
| - scripts
| - node_modules
```

In the app folder `tsc` is to write the compilation output. And in lib I copy the dist version if libraries used (using gulp).
And then of course, the scripts folder houses the typescript sources.

`tsc` is executed by running `tsc -p scripts` while standing on top level.

tsconfig.json as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/app/",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

And the issue? As soon as I add the line

```
import { UISEMANTIC_ALL } from "ng2-semantic-ui-directives/ng2-sui";
```

right after the other imports, and add the imported directive to the directives clause of the component (any component), no output is written.
There are no errors in console and all other files get refreshed - but not the file where this has been included. Removing this line again will make the file output properly from compilation.

I've had this issue before with other libraries - but I am using several different libraries without issue.

Also, if I comment out `outDir` from the tsconfig the file outputs properly, albeit in the wrong location.
What am I missing?

Comment: Don't you have any error at all in your shell ? This is weird... What about the `ng2-semantic-ui-directives/ng2-sui` ? Are you sure about the path ? Can we see your systemjs.config.js ? Also, what if you delete all compiled js files and restart tsc ? Try also to start tsc from the root and change "outDir" to "./wwwroot/app/" just in case.

Comment: As I said, no errors in shell/console. As far as I can see - compilation succeeds but no output is written, which would mean that all paths are correct (and Visual Studio resolves modules correctly). Since this is before loading in browser, what does systemjs.config.js have to do with it, afaik that is used only when loading in browser? I've tried moving the tsconfig and running tsc from root folder - no change.

Comment: Ok. I found some elements saying that in the case where you have empty file output with no error, its a problem of module resolving which create the file, then re-create it empty. What if you remove the `"module": "commonjs"` option ?

Comment: No luck - I even cycled thru the different available options for that property. It doesn't even create an empty file - there's no output at all.

Comment: As soon as I comment out outDir - it compiles and outputs, but then in the "wrong" place.